# Getting ID from URL when nested and not nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, nested

I have a Client model, and nested in that, I have a Program model. Ex:

```
localhost:3000/clients/2
localhost:3000/clients/2/programs/5
```

In my ApplicationController class, I want to be able to load in the Client model object in the before_filter. I tried doing it like this:

```
@user_client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
```

This works for nested resources (localhost:3000/clients/2/programs/5) but it doesn't work for the client realm (localhost:3000/clients/2). If I do it this way:

```
@user_client = Client.find(params[:id])
```

It's the opposite - it works in the client realm (localhost:3000/clients/2) but not the nested resources (localhost:3000/clients/2/programs/5).

Is there a method that would work for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like:

```
@user_client = Client.find(params[:client_id] || params[:id])
```

So that if one is nil then the other one will be entered as the id.

Having them in this order means that it will always grab it if there is a `:client_id`.

The dangerous item though is that the id at the end of the link is called `:id` so there could be some confusion there if you are trying to identify records. Just be vigilant.

Comment: Ah, I thought there might be some "rails way" of doing it, but this does the trick. Thanks jstim!